# Set featured image as background in div

Tags: php, css, wordpress

After scouring the internet I found a way to set a Wordpress featured image as a background image in a div. The problem now is that I'm only ably set the styles for the background image of that div in-line. I want to be able to set the styles in my css file, but am unsure how.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
?>
<div style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) no-repeat center; width:100%; height: 300px; background-size:cover;"></div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS files are static, but WordPress's featured images and attachments are dynamic. The best way to handle this would be set the `background-image` inline, and set the rest of the background properties in the CSS file.

**PHP**

```
<div class="featured-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url( $src[0] ); ?>')"></div>
```

**HTML**

```
.featured-image {
    background: no-repeat center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: That did it! I unsuccessfully tried doing that before.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code with inline css `echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );`